# Covariance of INID order statistics

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, st.statistics

In the IID case, it is known that all order statistics are positively correlated.*  Thus, we know that $$\text{Cov}(X_{(i)},X_{(j)}) \geq 0.$$  Is this known in the INID (independent, non-identically distributed) case?  If it is not known, how could this be proved?  If it does not seem true, what would be a counter-example?

- E.g., see Bickel (1967), "Some contributions to the theory of order statistics"

Comment: the crosspost http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41438 has an answer

Comment: This question should be closed because it already has an answer at stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an example with **independent** variables and **negatively correlated** order statistics.  I can come close in two ways.

Here is an example with **uncorrelated** variables and **negatively correlated** order statistics.

[image]

Suppose the states of the world are the interval (-2,2), with variables
$A = |x|-2$, $B = -1$, $C = +1$, $D = x+1-\text{sign}(x)$.  Let $X=\{A,B,C,D\}$.  Then $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(3)}$ are negatively correlated.

Discretizing gives **independent** variables and **uncorrelated** order statistics.

Suppose there are four states of the world, and the four variables have values
depending on the states as $A=(0,-2,-2,0), B=(-1,-1,-1,-1), C=(1,1,1,1), D=(0,2,0,2)$.  Again let $X=\{A,B,C,D\}$. Then $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(3)}$ are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

If $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $(X_1,X_2) = (X,-X)$ the covariance of $(X^{(1)},X^{(2)})=\min(X_1,X_2),\max(X_1,X_2)$ is negative.

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent in your example.

Comment: Try the FKG inequality, I think product measures are fine even if not i.i.d. and (I think) the order stats are increasing fctns of the data.